# How do I set the paths for MSM in EE2?

Tags: expressionengine

I am setting up a second site using MSM in EE2. I have followed the instructions from EE but I keep getting the following error when I try to access the home page in the 2nd site:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct this: index.php

The second site is set as sub-domain as follows:

main site: http://174.121.46.122/~flowerwo/

sub-domain: http://174.121.46.122/~plants/

I have tried a server path and a url with no success:

$system_path = '/home/domain/public_html/system/';

I could use some help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpressionEngine's MSM ([Multiple Site Manager](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/sites/domainsetup.html)) works best using **virtual domains** or **subdomains** served off the same server.

The value for your `$system_path` variable will depend where on how you have the second domain's files relative to the first domain.

For example, if your directory structure looked like this:

```
└── domain1.com
    ├── admin.php
    ├── index.php
    ├── images
    ├── system
    └── themes
└── domain2.com
    ├── admin.php
    └── index.php
```

Then you could set your `$system_path` variable for `domain2.com` as:

```
$system_path = '../domain1.com/system/';
```

---

Your setup is slightly different, since you appear to be using [Apache's UserDir Module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html) for your domains instead of [VirtualHost Directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

I don't have any experience with this rather odd setup, but you may just need to adjust a few settings in your second domain's `admin.php` and `index.php` files:

```
$system_path = '../flowerwo/system/';
$assign_to_config['site_name'] = 'plants';
$assign_to_config['site_url']  = 'http://174.121.46.122/~plants/';
$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://174.121.46.122/~plants/admin.php';
```

*The value can either be relative or absolute from your ExpressionEngine system folder, though some servers may require a full, absolute path.*

---

If you want a bulletproof way of determining the server path for each of your MSM domains, upload a simple PHP file named `phpinfo.php` into the root of each domain:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load the page in your browser and look for the following variable:

```
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
```

The value of that variable will be the full path to your PHP Info script:

```
/home/domain/public_html/phpinfo.php
```

Remove the `phpinfo.php` part, add in the name of your system folder, `system`, and that will be the path to your MSM domain:

```
/home/domain/public_html/system
```

If ExpressionEngine still has problems, you might want to see if your server has any **PHP open_basedir** or **PHP SafeMode** restrictions in place (these settings will be determined by your web host).

Comment: Hi rjb, sorry to take so long to reply but I have been working on DNS issues. I am back to this question now, and see stuck. I have tried all of your suggestions, which I really appreciate you taking the time to provide. I have the server path correct, but I still get the same error that something is wrong in the index.php file. any other ideas?